# BeautifulSoup/Scraper Issues, No Text When Text Exists, doesn't move in between pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to write a little scraping project just to learn more about the whole thing and Python in general but I'm running into a few issues that I can't seem to solve despite my best efforts. The point of this is to look at my wishlist and generate a CSV file that I will then bump against a master list in Excel for status changes if things have come back in stock. Below is my code:

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

titles = []
links = []
price = []
addtocart = []

pages = np.arange(1, 10, 1)

for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://www.instocktrades.com/wishlists/defc57d9758f4ba89683abbc7a3d93?pg=" + str(pages), headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    wishlist_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='item thumbplus')

    sleep(randint(2,10))

for container in wishlist_div:

        #name
        name = container.find('div', class_='title').text.strip()
        titles.append(name)
        
        #link
        link = container.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'title'})
        for div in link:
            linking = container.find('a')['href']
            link = "https://www.instocktrades.com" + linking
        links.append(link)
        
        #price
        pricing = container.find('div', class_='price')
        price.append(pricing)
        
        #addtocart
        cart = container.find('button', class_='btn addtocart') if container.find('button', class_='btn addtocart') else 'Out Of Stock'
        addtocart.append(cart)

#building Pandas dataframe         
wishlist = pd.DataFrame({
'book': titles,
'link': links,
'price': price,
'cart': addtocart
})

wishlist.to_csv('wishlist.csv')
print(wishlist)
```

The problems I'm having are as follows:

1. It won't move to the next page of the website, I thought I had set this up correctly but it doesn't seem to want to do anything other than the first page.
2. For the price, if I add .text, I receive an Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', but leaving it as is extracts all the html into the CSV for it like such, I'd really like to just get the $27.99:

```
<div class="price">
                                $27.99
                            </div>
```

3. For the cart section, the point of seeing if an add to cart button exists obviously tells me if it's in stock or not. Once again if I try to add .text I get another Attribute Error for no text. If I leave it as is, it puts the whole html code again of the button like referenced below. What I'd like to achieve for this one is simply if the add to cart button exists return a value of "In Stock", it currently functions if it doesn't it will write "Out Of Stock".

```
<button class="btn addtocart" data-cart-qty="0" data-code="MAR201512" data-id="66791" data-title="A Walk Through Hell Complete HC (C: 0-1-0)" data-wl="3851484" title="Add to Cart" type="button">
<img alt="Add to Cart" src="/images/cart.png"/> Add to Cart
                                </button>
```

Definitely would appreciate any help I could get on rectifying these issues. Thank you!

Comment: For 1. you are looping 10 pages before moving to the for container loop. Move the for container loop inside for page loop. For 2. I think your class name is price not pricing. Didn't look at 3.

Comment: @JonathanLeon Ah yeah I forgot, there is a class of pricing that contains class price on the page, I updated it to the specificity of class price but still the same result of the AttributeError. I'm still new to Python so I forget that tabs matter, tabbing it over one resolved my issue of not going through all the pages. Thanks!

Comment: looking at your page loop, you have str(pages) instead of str(page). just a typo. that fixes your loop. but still need to indent your next for loop as mentioned earlier

Comment: see below on price section. you can use the same section to show out of stock, don't even need to use the button search. seems no price, no ability to add to cart. good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your price block. Just search class_='price'. The issue is some titles don't have prices.

```
    pricing = container.find('div', class_='price')
    if pricing:
        price.append(pricing.text)
        print(pricing.text)
    else:
        print('no pricing')
        price.append(0)
```

Partial output:

```
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/mar201512/a-walk-through-hell-complete-hc-(c-0-1-0)

                                $27.99
                            
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/jul170097/abe-sapien-dark-terrible-hc-vol-01
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/nov170018/abe-sapien-dark-terrible-hc-vol-02
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/mar180092/abe-sapien-drowning-other-stories-hc
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/may110255/absolute-all-star-superman-hc
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/dec180616/absolute-batman-arkham-asylum-hc-30th-anniv-ed
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/apr150293/absolute-batman-the-court-of-owls-hc
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/aug180594/absolute-batman-the-black-mirror-hc
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/feb201046/absolute-carnage-omnibus-hc
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/may190468/absolute-death-hc-new-ed-(mr)
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/aug190641/absolute-fourth-world-by-jack-kirby-hc-vol-01
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/jan160353/absolute-preacher-hc-vol-01-(mr)
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/nov160355/absolute-preacher-hc-vol-02-(mr)
no pricing
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/sep170442/absolute-preacher-hc-vol-03-(mr)

                                $87.00
                            
https://www.instocktrades.com/products/jul108195/absolute-sandman-vol-1-hc-(mr)

                                $57.99
```

Comment: Thanks that was a big help @Jonathan Leon I am receiving this error though: File "Restock_Script_2.py", line 54, in <module> wishlist = pd.DataFrame({ raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length") ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: see answer edit. need to add something to price list: price.append(0) in else statement

Comment: almost there! The CSV file it's generating I can get it to input "No Pricing" but the ones that are in stock with a price, the field is being left empty

Comment: got it! had to make a couple more tweaks, once I added strip() it started handling it properly, thanks so much for your help! @Jonathan Leon